# Perform a series of storyboard segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue, deep-linking

I have a storyboard with over 20 scenes. I want to be able to deep link to one of these scenes. In order to do so, I'd like to perform the necessary segues from my initial view controller.

So say I have view controllers A, B, and C with segues laid out as follows.

`->A --segue1--> B --segue2--> C`

What's the easiest way to get from A to C without adding special code to B? I need the unwind segues from C to B to remain intact. The only solution I've come up with to add special logic in B that performs segue2 after appearing if a flag is set. This is not ideal as I have some use-cases where this chain is much deeper. I'd rather have code in A that does something like `[A performSegues:[@"segue1", @"segue2"]]`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these all in a single `UINavigationController`? I.e. these are all push segues?

Comment: No. I've seen the solution that involves setting the viewControllers array of UINavigationController but some of the segues are modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setViewControllers:animated: to build the whole stack of view controllers that you want all at once. If you start with A, you can make a mutable copy of the navigation controller's viewControllers array, add as many other view controllers to it as you need, then pass that array to setViewControllers:animated:. If you set animated to YES, you will see a single push from A to what ever the last controller in the array is. You will still be able to use an unwind to go back to any of those controllers.

I don't think there's any good way to do this with segues, as you would see all the transitions from one controller to the next (unless that's what you want to see).

Comment: I don't mind seeing the intermediate views in a transition, but they're not necessarily all pushes onto a navigation controller. In the example above, segue1 is a "push" and segue2 is a "show modally".

Comment: @rgbrgb, If you want a mix of pushes and presentations, then I don't think there's any good way to do that. Personally, I think that UI where you would see a bunch of views being pushed and presented in rapid succession is not a good design.